# Need an IF function that shows the difference when one cell is greater than another and blank when not

Tags: microsoft-excel

This one has me stumped:
I have a spreadsheet that I need to know when I have a cell that is greater than another cell but show nothing when it doesn't.

Cell B9 is a sum of B2:B8 with these cells using information from other sheets in the workbook. Cell B13 is a number that I input.   I am trying to get the sum of B9-B13 only when it is greater than B13, I need this cell to be blank when the sum is equal to or less than B13.

I know I am missing something simple but I cannot get the cell blank when it needs be.
I am using Excel 2010, but it will also need to work in 2007 version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`=IF(B9>B13,B9-B13,"")` should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(SUM(B9:B13)>B13,SUM(B9:B13))`, perhaps?

Or, if by "the sum of" thou meanest "the result of", then `=IF(B9-B13>B13,B9-B13)` should do it.
If those don't work, try adding a `,""` before the closing bracket in whichever expression thou usest, to explicitly specify a blank value if the condition for the `IF` is false.